# cancel jupyter notebook display chinese on tool toolbar

Tags: jupyter-notebook, display

i never did anything but type the command `conda update --all`, when all finished, my jupyter notebook start to display Chinese on toolbar, but i hope it can still display English.

what can i do to restore this change, but keep the newest version of jupyter? my interface of jupyter notebook are look as the pic below(sorry that i can't post pic temporarily):

[image: my actual jupyter interface]